# Workflow Manager Configuration Wizard blocked ports

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, iis

I am running the Workflow Manager Configuration Wizard for Sharepoint 2013 workflows, but I am getting the flowing errors, I can't find anything on Google so I am hoping that someone here knows what to do?

Error 1: `Port Number 9355 specified for HTTPS port is blocked`

Error 2: `Port number 9002 specified for Internal Communication Port Range is blocked`.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Does not work for me, dont even see the Service Bus Gateway Service in services.msc or the Service Bus Message broker, so looking for why those two are not present, or if they even should be.

Comment: It's a helpful explanation and solution for **[Port number specified for internal communication Port Range is blocked](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/workflow-manager-port-is-blocked/)**

Comment: This is MS Bug in WebPI. I enabled TLS 1.0 while configuring the WFM. once it configured need to enable TLS 1.2. Make sure you use offline package installer and don't use WebPI

Answer (score 9):

Problem resolved after I stop those Windows Services! -

- Service Bus Gateway
- Service Bus Message Broker
- Windows Fabric Host Service

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Comment: Problem resolved after I stop those Windows Services! - Service Bus Gateway
Service Bus Message Broker
Windows Fabric Host Service The Solution Helped me :)

Comment: Worked. Make sure to restart the configuration manager. Simple going back and trying to configure will not work.

Comment: Take note of the poster's comments. you have to STOP those services and not restart them. After I STOPPED them, everything was fine.

Comment: Note this is the same as running `Stop-SBHost` in PowerShell

Comment: It worked. You just have to restart the wizard as @Flory wrote. Refresh button does not work.

Comment: That helped...Only restarted Service Bus Gateway...thanks

Answer (score 2):

It works for me.
I would like to notice that you should restart the configuration at the begining. if you did just a refresh (by clicking on a refresh button provided), it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Check your firewall settings and Disable any port listening whilst you are doing the install. You can Enable the rule again once you have completed the install. You will need to do this for both the Inbound and Outbound Rules.
Hope this helps.
[image: Firewall Rules]

Comment: I had to do this in addition to the first two answers for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

As per my post [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/116b2bdf-0d32-4211-9b55-b2feb4dc50b2/sharepoint-2013-local-install-blocked-ports#26755d5d-b196-4ef2-8c89-e39c34dd055e), I:

- Installed Service Bus and Workflow Manager Cumulative Updates on all servers (using the Web Platform Installer - be careful, it might reboot servers without warning!)
- Left the farm on the App Sever and created a new one using custom settings (had to specify another database name)
- The WFE's seemed to be in an inconsistent state: the Workflow Manager UI had 4 options (Create, Create [Custom], Join, and *Leave*). This was weird so I "left" the invalid farm (maybe it thought it had its own?). Then I joined with the new database names.

Aside:

- Originally the URL's were HOSTS entries and are now A Records. (Not sure if possible cause).
- Make sure you specify the correct account (I used Farm account - but it wanted to default to install account).
  Powershell commands failed with "access denied" but UI worked.
- Double-check your proxy settings.

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me too. The thing was that I already made a web application with the port number 9000. So you have to choose "Advanced settings" and set "Internal communication port range" to a new range. (For example: 8000).

That solved my problem.